# neo4j slows with rows inserted

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Database inserts seem to slow down with each batch.

Here is the insert code:

```
public class Write {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Connect con = new Connect();

    final Random rand = new Random(1);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long last = start;
    System.out.format("Idx\tLast\tAvg\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        final Transaction tx = con.session.beginTransaction();
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                final Man man = new Man(rand);
                con.session.save(man);
            }
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.rollback();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        tx.close();
        long loop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.format("%d\t%d\t%d\n", j, (loop-last), ((loop - start) / (j + 1)));
        last = loop;
    }

    long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.format("Time to run:%d(sec)\n", (stop - start) / 1000);

}
```

}

The connection is to  a locatl file:

```
public class Connect {

final public Session session;

public Connect() {
    final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.driverConfiguration()
            .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.driver.EmbeddedDriver")
            .setURI("file:///home/fodon/neo");

    final SessionFactory sessionFactory = new SessionFactory(configuration, "fod.neo.domain");
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
}
```

}

The objects are simple too:

```
public class Man extends Entity {

String name;
Set<Car> cars;

public Man() {

}

public Man(final Random rand) {
    name = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8);
    cars = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < rand.nextInt(10)+1; i++) {
        cars.add(new Car(rand));
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(String.format("%d:%s\n", getId(), name));
    for (Car car : cars) {
        sb.append("\t");
        sb.append(car.toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

The Car object stores the cars owned:

```
public class Car extends Entity {

String type;

public Car() {

}

public Car(Random rand) {
    type = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%d:%s\n", getId(), type);
}
```

}

Both are Entities:

```
public abstract class Entity {

@GraphId
protected Long id;

Entity() {

}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

}

The database seems to slow with each insert.

Idx Time(ms) for insert

0   8166

1   3682

2   4139

3   5416

4   6153

5   6852

6   8462

7   10211

8   11764

9   12825

10  14176

11  15548

12  16212

13  19995

14  23751

15  25247

16  26173

17  27535

18  28170

19  29541

20  29715

...

30  51122

It can't be scalable if it slows like this.
How can I speed this up?

Comment: Can you provide any relevant constraints or indexes set up here? Have you taken a look at some of the nodes created from the neo4j browser to see if they look as you expect, with the relationships and properties you expect?

Comment: There are no indexes or constraints. Yes, the data looks as expected.

Comment: Here is a link to a working project   https://www.dropbox.com/s/chyoxyw15r1e77z/neo.zip?dl=0

Comment: @fodon Hi, turns out I have a similar issue with querying the graph. As the graph size grows, my code that only query the graph (not with cypher though), slows down a lot. Did you manage to find where that came from?

Comment: No I switched to relational databases. I also think that setting up an index may help.